# Source for p-adic cyclotomic character

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

I am looking for some book or paper where the p-adic cyclotomic character $\chi _{p}:G\rightarrow {\mathbf  {Z}}_{p}^{\times }$ is defined (as in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_character). I want to use it as a reference in my thesis and therefore can not use the wikipedia page itself.

Comment: With $G = Gal(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$ and $p$-prime we have $g(\zeta_{p^k}) = \zeta_{p^k}^{\chi_{k}(g)}$ where $\chi_k :G \to (\mathbf{Z}/p^k \mathbf{Z})^\times$ is a character. It satisfies the compatibility $a_{k}(g) \equiv a_{m}(g) \bmod p^m$ for $m \le k$, therefore we can extend to a character $\chi : G \to \mathbf{Z}_p^\times, \chi(g) = (\chi_1(g),\chi_2(g),\chi_3(g),\ldots)$

Comment: You can cite say Neukrich's algebraic number theory book.